# Deep Links not redirecting to App when using iOS

Tags: ios, deep-linking

We set up universal links that work on android but don’t work on iOS when using Safari as the main browser. However, when we tested on Chrome it did work. Is this a known issue

Comment: So they work on chrome on iOS but not safari on iOS? or they work on chrome on Android but not safari on iOS?  Have you verified your apple app site association file is correct?

Comment: They work on Chrome on iOS but not safari on iOS.

Comment: Go in to the developer settings menu on your phone (it appears in settings after you connect your phone to Xcode) and you can enter a url and iOS will tell you that it is a registered universal link and which app will open.  Chrome is just a wrapper around WebKit (the same browser engine used by Safari) so I am surprised it works on Chrome but not on Safari.